# UIAlertView crash issue on another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uialertviewdelegate

I have 2 view controllers, `ViewController` 1(VC1) and 2(VC2). In VC2 I have a back and done button. On clicking back button it goes directly to VC1 and on done it makes an api call and when it gets a response it shows an alert view and clicking ok goes back to VC1. Now when I make a api call a loading bar shows up and disappears when I get response and shows the `AlertView`. But if during that fraction of second when the loading disappears and `AlertView` is going to be popped up if I click on back and the view changes to VC1, the alert appears on VC1 and results in a crash.

This is a rare case as no user will purposely try for it but I was wondering if that crash can be managed without disabling the back button. I think there can be other instance such cases like if we are making an asynchronous calls and if the user is allowed to use UI while waiting for response and if any error alert that was suppose to show on one `ViewController` shows up in another may result in crash since the delegate that alert is referring to is that of the previous view controller. So is there any way to handle this kind of crash efficiently?

```
//Alert View sample
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[[message objectAtIndex:1] capitalizedString] message:[message objectAtIndex:0] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] ;
[alert setTag:701];
[alert show];

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if ([alertView tag] == 701)
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }


}
```

Comment: Can you paste the entire crash log?

Comment: Does the crash happen after tapping the OK or simply when the alert appears?

Comment: i think that issue when alert open then currunt viewcontroller left to another view controller and alert still apear and when he/she tap on button on alert that popviewcontroller code runs and crash.

Comment: The Alert appears and clicking ok will crash it, because the delegate set to self which is suppose to show on VC2 shows in VC1.

Comment: is your code ARC enabled?

Comment: just for test.. comment other api calling code and directly call alert view n run.....  alert view have carsh ?

Comment: @Gamerlegend I can't reproduce this crash. Are you using ARC?

Comment: Yes, its ARC enabled, deployment target is 5.0

Comment: Try this approach instead. http://nscookbook.com/2013/04/ios-programming-recipe-22-simplify-uialertview-with-blocks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to fix this problem is to use an instance variable to keep a reference to the alert view.

This instance variable should be set to `nil` in the `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` delegate method.

In the view controller's `dealloc` method, you call `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:` if the instance variable is still set.

Assume `_alertView` is the instance variable.

Create the alert:

```
_alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[[message objectAtIndex:1] capitalizedString] message:[message objectAtIndex:0] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] ;
[_alertView setTag:701];
[_alertView show];
```

Update your existing `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if ([alertView tag] == 701) {
         _alertView.delegate = nil;            
         _alertView = nil;
        if (buttonIndex == 0) {
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Add:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    _alertView = nil;
}
```

Add:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    if (_alertView) {
        _alertView.delegate = nil;
        [_alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:_alertView.cancelButtonIndex animated:NO];
        _alertView = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: This work for issue but causing crash for normal flow, that is when I click done and click ok on alert goes back and then crashes.

Comment: Did you make the change to the `clickedButtonAtIndex:` method as I showed?

Comment: You may also need to add the line `_alertView.delegate = nil;` to your `clickedButtonAtIndex:` method (just before calling `_alertView = nil;`).

Comment: Ya I copy pasted your code. I tried the breakpoint inside dealloc, the _alertView is nil and it doesnt goes in but still crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS, commenting the dealloc code works fine.

Comment: This is how I declared the alertView interface ViewController ()
{UIAlertView * _alertView;} end 
implementation ViewController ....

Comment: Did you see my previous comment about the additional change to `clickedButtonAtIndex:`?

Comment: Ok, thats seems to work, one more doubt, why did u use dealloc, we can do this also in viewDidDisappear. Any specific reason?

Comment: Since `viewDidAppear` can be called for different reasons, I prefer to use `dealloc` for this kind of cleanup. But either should work.

Comment: @CrimsonChris Please add your comment to the question, not my answer.