# UIAlertView showing up in other view when going back fast to previous view controller

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uialertview

I am having a problem by my `UIAlertView`. I am using a `NSTimer` for showing an `UIAlertView` on a moment when my loop is done.

**The problem:**

My `UIAlertView` is popping up on my previous `ViewController` when I am pressing the back button fast, before the loop is done. So on that moment when the `UIAlertView` is showing up, my app will crash when pressing a button on the `UIAlertView`.

How can I check that the `ViewController` is still the delegate or something that it does not show up in an other view?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIAlertView crash issue on another view controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23509441/uialertview-crash-issue-on-another-view-controller)

Answer (score 0):

It is crashing because you have set the current View controller as delegate and while pressing back that is no more in memory when alert appears on the previous view while pressing back at the time the reference which delegate is handling is no more that why it is crashing.

[UIAlertView crash issue on another view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23509441/uialertview-crash-issue-on-another-view-controller)

Comment: Oke yeah, I understand that, but then how can I check that i does not show up in the other view?

Comment: you can check for class reference.

Comment: That answer is for handeling the "crash" so it will still show up in the other view controller. I do not want it to show there. Just a check for, are we still in the delegate class or something

Comment: this might help you-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399219/ios-dismiss-uialertview-beforing-showing-another